# PyAutoGUI not writing expected Output with python code

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyautogui

I have the problem that pyautogui doesn't write what I programmed into it.
When I try to use go_to it writes it incorrectly.
I have written this code:

```
import pyautogui as pag 
import time

def open_chat():
    pag.write("t")

def close_chat():
    pag.press("esc")

def go_to(x, y, z):
    pag.write(" #goto", x, y, z)

print("start")

time.sleep(20)
open_chat()
go_to(x= 1,y= 1, z= 1)


print("ende")
```

I expected that the code gives me this output:

```
t #goto 1 1 1
```

but I got this output:

```
t 'goto
```

I have tried to change the code a few times but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Pyautogui's](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/e869e5dd9c36022631888555776749ca2f70382b/pyautogui/__init__.py#L1644) `write` (which is an alias for `typewrite`) functions differently than [Python's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) built-in `print` function. If you look at the function signatures you'll see how `print` accepts an arbitrary number of objects to print, and `typewrite`  accepts a single message to type. The `*` before `objects` in the signature indicates that it will accept 0 or more positional arguments, and that a tuple of all arguments passed will be assigned to the variable `objects` in the function's body.

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None, flush=False)
typewrite(message, interval=0.0, logScreenshot=None, _pause=True)
```

When you call `pag.write(" #goto", x, y, z)` only the first object is typed. Best practice would be to generate a string containing the entirety of what you want typed into the field, and pass that single string to `typewrite`. String concatenation works, as does [string interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting), but [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), or [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) are recommended.